# What is the reapplication process for a suspended dispatcher certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, dispatch

I had my dispatcher certificate suspended for a year for leaving the testing site before I could provide an adequate urine sample.

I did not realize this was a reportable event. I accept the suspension but am looking for the process to follow to get reinstated after the 1 year period.

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about this, but [JO 2150.3C](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1034329) says that if a certificate is *suspended* for a fixed period of time, it's reinstated at the end of that time if you meet whatever conditions the FAA requires (p. 7-4):

> Indefinite suspensions are used when the Administrator has reason to
>   question, but is unable to determine, a certificate holder’s
>   qualifications, or when the certificate holder does not comply with
>   statutory or regulatory requirements to cooperate with the FAA. For
>   indefinite suspensions, the Administrator suspends the certificate
>   until certain conditions are met, e.g., until a reexamination or
>   reinspection under 49 U.S.C. § 44709(a) is successfully completed. The
>   period of time the certificate is not effective is specified in the
>   order of suspension, and once the required period has passed, the
>   certificate is reinstated.

Your question doesn't have many details - and I understand that you might not want to share them! - but I take that to mean that if your certificate was suspended for one year, it will be reinstated after one year has passed, as long as you've done whatever the FAA wants you to do in order to qualify for reinstatement.

The phrase "until certain conditions are met" implies that there's no standard way to qualify to reinstatement; it probably depends on the reason that the certificate was suspended in the first place. Page 9-15 of the order lists reasons for suspension and they're quite varied, so presumably the "certain conditions" are too.

On the other hand, if a certificate is *revoked* then it cannot be reinstated (p. 7-4):

> Unlike a suspension, a certificate that has been revoked cannot be
>   reinstated. A person whose certificate has been revoked may be issued
>   a new certificate provided that the person meets the qualification
>   requirements for the new certificate. To be issued an airman
>   certificate following revocation, an individual must retake all tests,
>   whether written, oral, or practical.

Your local FSDO could probably confirm that, although if your situation is more complicated then an aviation lawyer might be more helpful.

Comment: Suspensions are not automatically reinstated. Suspensions happen because the person failed to do something or did something wrong, and reinstatements take place after the person has taken some action to mitigate the reason for the suspension, such as counselling, training or passing an examination.

Comment: @JuanJimenez Thanks! I've updated my answer

Answer (score -2):

There is no FAR that says your certificate would be suspended for **leaving** the test site. It is more likely that the suspension was given because your leaving and not returning after being asked to provide the urine sample was interpreted as a refusal to provide the sample. That *is* grounds for suspension of the certificate. To get it reinstated you need to apply for the certificate following the normal process and take the test(s) again, and don't forget you'll need to provide that urine sample if you are asked for it.